# PHP - Text on image with multiple styles/colors

Tags: php, gd

I've got a problem with adding text to images.

Does anyone happen to know a way to add a text with multiple styles/colors/fonts to an image? The solutions i saw only permitted to add them in different text blocks, but I need to do it in the same block.

Any help will be much appreciated

Here's what I would like the final result to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Hsz.jpg

Comment: Then create four blocks with different styles. It seems you asked the question before you even tried. Did you make any attempts or did you just read one "solution" and then came here?

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically edit an image so that the text is part of the image, or are you trying to overlay an image with text? Can you show us an example of what you've done so we can tell you how to modify it?